# convert instance variable to String?

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there a simple way to convert an instance variable to a String?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this (a bit safer because it will still work if `myInstanceVariable` is null):

```
String(myInstanceVariable)
```

or

```
myInstanceVariable.toString()
```

Also, I just found this nice article explaining the different methods: http://www.morearty.com/blog/2008/07/28/actionscripts-different-ways-to-convert-an-object-to-a-string/

Answer (score 0):

for string I always use `myStringVar = myInstance + "";`